# How do I get the jQuery keypad plugin to work with List.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently designing a UI for an automated parking system. One of the pages (garage status) has a table which contains spot numbers and their corresponding ticket numbers. The valet has to be able to type in either a spot number or ticket number into the search box and as he types each letter, the options in the table are filtered according to what he types. I'm using List.js for this, however, I also need to have an onscreen keypad for the valet to input the numbers, which for that I use jQuery Keypad plugin. Unfortunately, filtering is only performed if I directly input from my laptop keyboard, not when I use the keypad plugin. I would be very grateful if someone could give some input on how to solve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Garage Status</title>

    <head>
        <!-- Import materialize.css -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css"/>
        <!--Import Material Design icons-->
    <link href="font/material-design-icons/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--Import jQuery before materalize.js-->
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
     <!--Import jQuery Keypad CSS-->
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.keypad.aps.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.keypad.js"></script>

    <!--Touchscreen keypad for ticket num input just in case ticket scanner doesn't work or they want to edit the ticket number (e.g.ticket scanner makes mistake)-->
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#grgKeypad').keypad({target: $('.search'),layout: ['789'+ $.keypad.CLEAR,'456' + $.keypad.BACK,'1230-']
        });
      });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Page Title Panel-->
        <div class="card-panel">
            <h4>GARAGE STATUS</h4>
            <!--Options button, reveals dropdown menu with options to switch to other pages-->
            <a id="optionsbtn" class='dropdown-button btn-large' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1' data-constrainwidth='false'>Options</a>
            <!--Quick access buttonss to inpark and outpark menus-->
            <a id="quick_outpark_btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" href="outmenu.html">OUTPARK</a>
            <a id="quick_inpark_btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" href="inmenu.html">INPARK</a>
        </div>
        <!--Dropdown menu structure and it's items-->
        <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="dashmenu.html">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="inmenu.html">Inpark</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="outmenu.html">Outpark</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="shufflemenu.html">Shuffle</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="qmenu.html">Outpark Queue Menu</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="transactions.html">Transactions</a></li>
    </ul>
        <!--Dashboard Button, press to return to dashboard-->
        <div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
            <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light" href="dashmenu.html">
                <!--Home icon-->
                <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 48px">&#xE637;</i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!--Form that takes ticket number or spot number and searches for that car's ticket number and spot number-->
        <!--Note that the search form shouldn't be sending data back to the server to search for the car, the data should already be loaded onto the page and the search should be performed with the already loaded data or something like that idk if you want to change-->
        <div id="locations">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="col s7" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s9">
                            <input placeholder="Enter ticket or spot number" id="search" type="search" class="search">
                            <label for="search"><i class="material-icons" id="searchicon"style="font-size: 48px">&#xE661;</i></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        <!--Table that displays cars in the garage-->
        <!--Data will be dynamically displayed, currently these are just placeholder data-->
            <div class="table" id="searchtable">
                <table class="centered striped bordered scroll">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Spots</th>
                            <th>Ticket Number</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="list">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="spot">1-22-35</td>
                            <td class="ticketnum">696969</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="spot">1-22-34</td>
                            <td class="ticketnum">696968</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="spot">6-22-33</td>
                            <td class="ticketnum">696967</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="spot">1-22-32</td>
                            <td class="ticketnum">696966</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="spot">8-22-31</td>
                            <td class="ticketnum">696965</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="spot">8-22-30</td>
                            <td class="ticketnum">696964</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="spot">1-22-39</td>
                            <td class="ticketnum">696953</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
        <!--Div containing the keypad-->
        <div id="grgKeypad"></div> 

        <!--Import List.js-->
        <script src="list.js"></script>
        <script>
            var options = {
                valueNames: ["spot","ticketnum"]
            };

            var userList = new List("locations",options);
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```